# Covert this list in python in the following format

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What I want is:

```
a = 0, 2
b = 1, 4
c = 3
```

I have spent around an hour trying to do this by playing with zip() but didn't work. How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in zip(b, a):
    result[item].append(idx)
print result
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [1, 4]})
```

If `b` is always a list of indices, you can simply use `enumerate`

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(a):
    result[item].append(idx)
print result
```

Comment: +1: a dictionary will not pollute your namespace.

Comment: b is always list of indices.

Comment: Thank you sir, Will accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [i for x, i in zip(a, b) if x == 'a']
[0, 2]
>>> [i for x, i in zip(a, b) if x == 'b']
[1, 4]
>>> [i for x, i in zip(a, b) if x == 'c']
[3]
```

or using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 'a']
[0, 2]
```

Comment: yes, but I want 'a', 'b', 'c' to be dynamic.

Comment: @user2032220, Then, thefourtheye's answer is what you want. :)

Comment: @user2032220, Not recommended, but you can also do to get a dictionary (Python 2.x): `reduce(lambda d, (i,x): [d.setdefault(x, []).append(i), d][1], enumerate(a), {})`

Comment: @user2032220, (Python 3.x): `from functools import reduce; reduce(lambda d, ix: [d.setdefault(ix[1], []).append(ix[0]), d][1], enumerate(a), {})`

Answer (score 0):

Incase if your list b is indices always, you can do it this way...

**code:**

```
d={}
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']


for item in set(a):
    d[item] = [i for i,val in enumerate(a) if val==item]

print d
```

**output:**

```
{'a': [0, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [1, 4]}
```

If not your list b is indices, the same can be accomplished as...

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

d= defaultdict(list)
for (p,q) in zip(a,b):
    d[p].append(q)

print d
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [1, 4]})
```

Hope this helps :)